# How do I get \texttt with bold face in LaTeX?

Tags: fonts, bold, typewriter

This question was asked and answered [20 years ago](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/HSB7jQX4A0w) but I wonder if there is a more modern solution today that does not involve quite so much hackery with overriding settings in font files.

I want my font to look exactly like the result of `\texttt` but in bold face.

How might I achieve this?

Comment: I would guess the same solution still holds. Mainly that `\texttt` (using Computer Modern Typerwriter font) does not have a **bold** font. So you'd have to get a bold typewriter font first...

Comment: @Werner, In 20 years we have not created a bold typewriter font that looks like Computer Modern with bold?

Comment: i did this 30+ years ago, for a special project.  the problem is, cmtt is too heavy to support a bold that is readable, and not bold enough to look bold unless the companion lightface is so light that it breaks up in printing.  so two new fonts had to be created -- one lighter and one bolder.  (they were never released.)  latin modern has fixed the problem.

Comment: Use the courier font: `\usepackage{courier}` - see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/619953/171556

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use Bera Mono:

```
[...]
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}%% Only as example for the romans/sans fonts
\usepackage[scaled=0.85]{beramono}
[...]
\begin{document}
\texttt{\textbf{foo}}
```

Comment: `libertine` is too wide. `beramono` seems to make no difference

Answer (score 48):

There are the [Latin Modern Fonts](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lm), from their [README](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/lm/README):

> The fonts are based on Donald E. Knuth's Computer Modern fonts in the
>   PostScript Type 1 format

In family `lmtt`, there are even three series:

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\ttfamily
\fontseries{l}\selectfont light
\fontseries{m}\selectfont medium
\fontseries{b}\selectfont bold
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

They are also available in OpenType font format with
a math version.

The number of glyphs is dramatically increased in comparison to
the old Computer Modern fonts.

Thus indeed much has happened in the last twenty years.

Comment: `cfr-lm` includes commands to switch analogous to the standard end-user font commands e.g. `\textlg{}` and `\lgweight`. (Not `series` because that conflates two dimensions of fonts: weight and width.)

Comment: Can I choose a level for the keywords in a lstlisting?

Comment: @user4417 This question seems unrelated to this question or this answer. Therefore I suggest making a new question.

Answer (score 24):

I just ran across it and found a simpler answer here:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Fonts

```
\usepackage{bold-extra}
...
\texttt{TT Text \textbf{Bold TT Text}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Note that the site you say the excerpt is from has the code snippet as `\textsc{TT Text \textbf{Bold TT Text}}`, *not* as `\texttt{TT Text \textbf{Bold TT Text}}`. Please indicate how you can get your code snippet to work.

Comment: It's not working with \texttt{}, only with \textsc{}.

Comment: Prompted by another answer/comment, I tried this myself, and it works for me on TeX Live 2017 on macOS. (`\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bold-extra}
\begin{document}
\texttt{TT Text \textbf{Bold TT Text}}
\end{document}`) The first time I ran it, METAFONT was invoked (via `mktextfm` via `kpathsea`) to create the font `cmttb10`. Note that this is a bitmap font (and with sufficient zoom visible as such in the PDF), but at typical print and screen resolutions, this is not a problem.

Comment: I will remember this one! +1

Comment: This is great, and a solution that "just works" in the way you'd hope +1.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved the same problem. I'm using a ready-made template where individual packages are often colliding. Verbatim fragments (`verb`, `texttt`) overflow the page. I finally decided to go with the not exactly correct solution.

```
{\fontfamily{lmtt}\fontseries{b}\selectfont my coding in text}
```

I only changed the font style for the text to bold Latin Modern Sans Typewriter.