# bold just one line inside of lstlisting

Tags: formatting, listings, bold

How can i bold just one line in this code?

```
\begin{lstlisting}
//Algoritmo 2
    int f2 ( n ):
    local i , j , r =0;
    para i = 1 a n -1
        para j = i +1 a n
            r = r + 2;
            cont++;
    retorna r ;
\end{lstlisting}
```

I just want to bold `cont++`
I tried to use `\textbf` but no success..

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to use the `escapeinside` command, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    escapeinside={(*}{*)}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
//Algoritmo 2
    int f2 ( n ):
    local i , j , r =0;
    para i = 1 a n -1
        para j = i +1 a n
            r = r + 2;
            (*\bfseries cont++;*)
    retorna r ;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, depending on what else you've put in your `\lstset`, this approach may or may not work. In particular, it's common to put code listings in `monospaced font`, and if so, you'll have to use [one of the solutions to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215482/how-do-i-get-texttt-with-bold-face-in-latex) to get a monospaced bold font.

Comment: Actually, it worked perfectly. Thank you :)

Comment: If you wish to maintain the same spacing used by `lstlisting`, you should use `(*\aftergroup\bfseries*) ... (*\aftergroup\mdseries*)`...