# Bold font style in \verb environment

Tags: verbatim, bold

I'm looking to get a \verb string to output with bold font style as well as word wrapping. The closest I've come is by using the commented code rather than the currently live one. I realize I'm breaking the cardinal rule of never using \BF. I couldn't repeat the results with \textbf nor with \bfseries. Any thoughts on that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern,verbatim}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{boldverb}
{\def\@xobeysp{\ }
%{\def\@xobeysp{\bf \ }
        \verbatim\rightskip=0pt plus 6em\relax}
    {\endverbatim}
    \makeatother
    
    \begin{document}
        \begin{boldverb}
            \ \verb|\hspace{20pt}\newpageOkay, so where do we start, right? \textbf{Why is it that I can bold this stuff} but not \verb|
        \end{boldverb}
    \end{document}
```

Even if I'm allowed in this case to use \bf, the beginning of the string is always going to have to be a backslash. Is there a latex argument that recognizes elements such as Word-Initial or Word-Final?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Welcome! It's not really clear what you want to do: using `\verb` inside a verbatim environment will do nothing at all except printing `\verb`.

Comment: You seem to understand. I'm looking to utilize \verb, but I'm also looking for a way to manipulate the font style of the text. I just realized now that even when I get the space, all the remaining backslashes turn into quotes. I can settle for not being able to get the output with word wrapping, but I want a different font style.

Comment: The verbatim environment is in the preamble so I can manipulated the \verb output in a way to revise certain font attributes. That's the closest way I found to do it.

Comment: Maybe something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299401/bold-just-one-line-inside-of-lstlisting? Possibly combined with https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27663/using-bold-italic-text-inside-listings if you want a monospaced font for the verbatim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what your aim is.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fvextra}

\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{boldverb}{Verbatim}{
  fontfamily=\rmdefault,
  fontshape=\updefault,
  fontseries=bx,
  breaklines,
  breakanywhere,
  breaksymbolleft=,
  breakindent=0pt,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{boldverb}
\ \verb|\hspace{20pt}\newpageOkay, so where do we start, right? \textbf{Why is it that I can bold this stuff} but not \verb|
\end{boldverb}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It all started out because I wanted to explain how I came out with a command \verb+\enquote{\blash paragraph\{\blash hspace\{20pt\!\}\}.}+ but couldn't get it in bold, so I had to write it out as "\verb|\textbf{$\backslash$verb+$\backslash$enquote\{$\backslash$paragraph\{$\backslash$hspace$\backslash$\{20pt\!\}\}.\}+.}| \par"
I like your preamble. Is it something that could be placed in a .sty, or is it like \makeatletter?
FYI, that code won't make any sense in your editor, as it has newcommands in it

Comment: This actually solved another issue I was have with \enquote! Wow. You totally nailed it. The preamble is quite elegant. I look forward to studying it!

Answer (score 0):

While `\detokenize` is not the same as `verbatim`, it may suffice, depending on whether your input follows certain rules (e.g., balanced braces, no `%`, etc.).  Making it bold is straightforward.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\textbf{\detokenize{            \ \verb|\hspace{20pt}\newpageOkay, so where do we start, right? \textbf{Why is it that I can bold this stuff} but not \verb| 
\bgroup{} blah blah\egroup}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. It even has word wrapping. Than you much!