# sans-serif font in text, monospace serif within algorithm

Tags: fonts, pseudocode

In my .tex document I use sans-serif font with \sffamily. (And I don't want this to be monospace!)

For my algpseudocode I tried using \texttt. (For I want using a serif monospace font.)

### Please take a look at this minimal example

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,english]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm,footskip=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\title{Example Document}

\begin{document}
\sffamily

\section{some content}
So, that's what my written content looks like. Sans-serif. Pretty nice, eh?

\texttt %When I remove this line, no error at all!

\begin{algorithmic}
\State x = 0
\While{x < 10}
  \State x = x+1
\EndWhile
\end{algorithmic}

\sffamily

But for some reason, this doesn't work.

\end{document}
```

I always keep those errors:

```
monospace-algorithm.tex:19: Paragraph ended before \text@command was complete. []
monospace-algorithm.tex:19: Too many }'s. []
```

- What is `\text@command`?
- I counted the `}` and the `{`. Their number seems correct.
- Where do those come from?
- How to make the pseudocode monospace? (I prefer to use standard commands like `\sffamily` instead of fonts.)

Comment: Unlike `\sffamily`, which is a switch and affects all text in the group after it, `\texttt` is a macro that usually only applies to its argument: `\texttt{foo} bar`. In the example `\texttt` does not have an  argument and that might be problematic. You could go with the switch `\ttfamily` instead. But I'm quite sure there is a more elegant solution that does not require using all those font commands manually in the document.

Comment: thanx for \ttfamily. unfortunately, it breaks the pseudocode formatting.

Comment: You mean the bold? Yes, it is a well-known 'feature' of the default monospace font that it does not come with a bold series. You could try `\usepackage{lmodern}` where the bold is not very pronounced or look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/215482/35864

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`algorithm` contains a hook that you can redefine to set the font to a mono-spaced font.

In line with moewe's comment, you can use the `lmodern` package to get bold mono-spaced font.

Put this in your preamble:

```
% needed for bold tt font
\usepackage[lighttt]{lmodern}
% use sans serif by default
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
% use ttfamily for algorithm
\makeatletter
\algrenewcommand\ALG@beginalgorithmic{\ttfamily}
\makeatother
```

## MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,english]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm,footskip=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

% needed for bold tt font
\usepackage[lighttt]{lmodern}
% use sans serif by default
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
% use ttfamily for algorithm
\makeatletter
\algrenewcommand\ALG@beginalgorithmic{\ttfamily}
\makeatother

\title{Example Document}

\begin{document}

\section{some content}
So, that's what my written content looks like. Sans-serif. Pretty nice, eh?

\begin{algorithmic}
\State x = 0
\While{x < 10}
  \State x = x+1
\EndWhile
\end{algorithmic}

Now this works.

\end{document}
```

[image]