# Alltt package: Wrap Text

Tags: input, wrap

I have some text files that I what to include in a LaTex file. I would like to execute any (La)TeX commands in the text, but ignore any non-LaTex.

Here is the text:

> Contrary to popular belief, \textbf{Lorem Ipsum} is not simply random
> text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45
> BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin
> professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the
> more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and
> going through the cites of the word in classical literature,
> discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections
> 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise
> on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The
> first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from
> a line in section 1.10.32.
>
> The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced
> below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de
> Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their
> exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914
> translation by H. Rackham.

I use the alltt (see more here: http://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-verbfile) package to inlcude it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{alltt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{alltt}
    \input{text.txt}
    \end{alltt}
\end{document}
```

but the text is not wrapped:

[image]

Comment: How exactly should your output look like? Like that? https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWHSs.png

Comment: @leandriis Yes, exactly !

Answer (score 2):

Probably the following is closer to the desired output. I did not use `alltt` but simply switched to monospaced font using `\ttfamily`. Since the default Computer Modern font does not ofer a combination of typewriter like and bold font, I switched to Courier. Alternatives and more information on this topic can be found here:

[How do I get \texttt with bold face in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/215482/134144)

[Using \ttfamily with \bfseries (or how to enable bold in fixed-width font)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33039/134144)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}
{\ttfamily
    Contrary to popular belief, \textbf{Lorem Ipsum} is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

    The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
}
\end{document}
```

---

With an external file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}
{\ttfamily
\input{text.txt}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks ! does it work with an external text file?

Comment: @james: Yes, it does.

Comment: My apologies, but I don't see how to do it. Would you mind sharing an example LaTex code?

Comment: I have updated my answer accordingly. You should now be able to use the `\text.txt` file from your original question.

Comment: Oh great! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Following problem: If I add a random "^2" anywhere in the text it does not work. I was looking for a solution that executes any LaTeX, but ignores and just re-prints as-is any non-LaTeX. Do you see how to solve that?

Comment: What would you expect from this random `^2`? Do you want a superscript 2 or do you literally want ^2 in your output? Please clarify.

Comment: Yes, sorry for that: I would like to have the following behavior: If there is a character or set of characters in the input text that LaTeX does not know how to interpret (i.e. "^2"), it should just re-print them as-is. Hence, for this particular case, I would expect a "^2" in the output document. Does this make more sense?

Comment: Maybe in other words: I would like to have everything from the input text re-printed in the final document without any change, but the LaTeX code.