# Use the bold typewriter font from lmodern for keywords in listings but keep Computer Modern fonts in the rest of document in LaTeX

Tags: listings, bold, typewriter, lmodern

I am writing a document in LaTeX using the standard Computer Modern fonts. The text is mainly in Russian but it includes some listings. I prefer to typeset listings using the standard typewriter font (`\ttfamily`). It would be really nice if I could use a bold typewriter font for keywords in listings.

If my document was in English only, I would use the [bold typewriter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/215489/209093) font from `lmodern`:

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{%
basicstyle=\ttfamily\fontseries{l}\selectfont,
keywordstyle=\ttfamily\fontseries{b}\selectfont
}
```

However, this cannot be used in my case because `lmodern` does not support Cyrillic. But what is (theoretically) good is that all the keywords in listings contain Latin letters only. Consequently, my idea is to use the bold typewriter `lmodern` font (i.e., `\ttfamily\fontseries{b}\selectfont`) for keywords in listings and to keep Computer Modern fonts in the rest of my document (including the non-keyword entries in listings which contain strings and comments in Russian). Unfortunately, I do not know how to do it. It seems that when I load `lmodern` package, it changes the fonts throughout the entire document and I lose much of font formatting because of Russian letters. Could someone please help me with this?

Importantly, I need to use LaTeX only (not XeLaTeX, not LuaLaTeX). And I should probably note that the bold typewriter font specifically from `lmodern` is not really important, I just like how it looks.

Comment: remove lmodern and change `\ttfamily` to `\fontfamily{lmtt}` in keywordstyle

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, in this case, my keywords appear not in a bold typewriter font but in a regular non-bold serif (roman) font.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, oh, I finally got it! The problem was that I did not switch the font encoding. I will update my question shortly.

Comment: it is always best to include _complete_ small test documents in questions

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I've just updated my post and included the complete test document. Thank you very much for your answer! I had no idea I could use ```lmtt``` without loading ```lmodern``` package.

Comment: please don't add solutions to the question, it messes up the question and answer site format, you can post it as an answer, thanks

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I moved it to the answer. Sorry for messing things up.

Comment: no harm done:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to **David Carlisle** and **egreg**, I came up with this solution:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{%
basicstyle=\ttfamily,
keywordstyle=\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{lmtt}\bfseries
}

\begin{document}

Русский текст. \textbf{Жирный шрифт.}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
def func(s):
    return s
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: `\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{lmtt}\bfseries` is simpler and conceptually better.

Comment: @egreg, thank you very much for your comment. Indeed, it is better. I've just updated my answer.