# Combine \textbf and \texttt

Tags: fonts, text

I'm trying to combine `\textbf{}` with `\texttt{}` to obtain a code style that is more "fat". I tried to combine first `\textbf` and then `\texttt` and viceversa but nothing changed, it seems like `\texttt` has a priority over `\tetxbf`:

[image]

Comment: You need to use a font which has a bold typewriter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **Courier** teletype font family provides both a light/regular  and a bold font weight, with the weights looking very distinct.

[image]

Other teletype font families, including **Latin Modern Mono**, provide regular and bold font weights as well; however, their looks aren't as different from one another as in the case of the Courier teletype font.

[image]

To generate the preceding screenshot, just replace `\usepackage{courier}` with `\usepackage{lmodern}` in the code shown below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{courier} % or: \renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}
\begin{document}
Example \textbf{Example} \texttt{Example} \texttt{\textbf{Example}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Inconsolata is another one they might want to try out.

Comment: @Davislor - I fully agree. As a general proposition, I'd say that it can't be a good idea to use a monospaced font whose regular and bold font weights are so similar as to leave readers unsure as to whether a given monospaced word is typeset in regular or bold. That's why I held up Courier as a font to consider using. Inconsolata/Consolas is definitely a fine choice as well.

Answer (score 4):

With `contour` package, you can get fatter characters as a type of special effect when the contourlength is set to a relatively small amount:

[image: contour]

(`contour` is designed for printing readable text on top of images, and usually the contour colour would be white or some other light colour)

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{contour}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily{\ffmono}{Noto Sans Mono}
\newfontfamily{\ffcourier}{Courier New}
\newcommand{\testtext}{%
\par\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{ll}
font regular &  plain  \\
font bold& \textbf{bold} \\
contour& \contour{black}{bold} \\
contour red and yellow& \contour{red!20}{bold} \contour{yellow}{bold} \\
fatter contour& \contourlength{0.05em} \contour[40]{black}{bold} \contour[40]{red!20}{bold} \contour[40]{yellow}{bold} \\
\end{tabular}
\par
}

\begin{document}
\ttfamily
Default font
\testtext
\bigskip\ffcourier Courier New
\testtext
\bigskip\ffmono Noto Sans Mono
\testtext
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

**1.** [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\ttfamily
\fontseries{l}\selectfont light
\fontseries{m}\selectfont medium
\fontseries{b}\selectfont bold
\end{document}
```

2. [image: List item]

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   % \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage{lmodern}
   \usepackage{bold-extra}

   \begin{document}
   \textbf{qwe} \texttt{qwe} \texttt{\textbf{qwe}}
   \end{document}
   ```

Comment: I think this answer would benefit from some additional explenations. Especially to make it more clear that the first example works because of `lmodern` and not because it uses `\fontseries{b}` directly. Also the second example  does not need `bold-extra` since it loads `lmodern`. Maybe you wanted to omit that package there?